# Is this the correct way to assign a pointer to an object into a function?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

Say that I have this object:

```
class Game{
public:
    void SetPointer(D2DResources&);

public:
    D2DResources* pD2DResources;
};
```

with this function:

```
void Game::SetPointer(D2DResources& p)
{
    pD2DResources=&p;
}
```

And I do that in my WinMain:

```
Game game;

D2DResources d2DResources();

game.SetPointer(d2DResources);
```

Will it work? If not, what is the correct way to do it? The idea is to later access d2DResources' functions like this:

```
pGame->pD2DResources->OnRender();
```

pGame being a pointer to the above game object.

Comment: I tend to pass pointers instead of references if the receiver keeps a copy of the pointer but that's a matter of convention. But the key question is the question of ownership. Who shall own the D2DResources?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the pointed-to instance is kept alive, I see no problem with your approach. But it seems you want to declare the instance in a function `WinMain`, in which case it won't work.

Let's get one nit out of the way first: The following line

```
D2DResources d2DResources();
```

will declare a function which returns a `D2DResources` and with no parameters and not a variable of type `D2DResources`. If you want the latter, drop the brackets:

```
D2DResources d2DResources;
```

Now, if you want to keep the instance alive for a longer time, you should use a `std::shared_ptr`. An example could look like this:

```
class Game{
public:
    void SetPointer(D2DResources&);

public:
    std::shared_ptr<D2DResources> pD2DResources;
};

void Game::SetPointer(std::shared_ptr<D2DResources> p)
{
    pD2DResources=p;
}
```

and in `WinMain`, use:

```
Game game;

auto d2DResources = std::make_shared<D2DResources>();

game.SetPointer(d2DResources);
```

the usage stays the same as you wanted.